# Instafeed filter data into different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, instagram, instafeedjs

I have 4 divs & I want to show 20 results as below:

Div 1 - first 5 feeds

Div 2 - next 5 feeds (exclude first 5)

Div 3 - next 5 feeds (exclude first 10)

Div 4 - next 5 feeds (exclude first 15)

**HTML**

```
<ul id="instafeed2" class="instafeed slides"></ul>
<ul id="instafeed3" class="instafeed slides"></ul>
<ul id="instafeed4" class="instafeed slides"></ul>
<ul id="instafeed5" class="instafeed slides"></ul>
```

**JS**

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'user',
        userId: userId,
        accessToken: 'accessToken',
        limit:10,
        template: '<li><a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /></a></li>',
        resolution: 'standard_resolution',
        target: 'instafeed2',
    });

feed.run();
```

**Plugin url :** http://instafeedjs.com/
[Instafeed](http://instafeedjs.com/)

I am able to fetch result but unable to split them.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can split the feeds into different divs. In-order to achieve this;

1. override the success call back implementation, it provides the feasibility to control the feed data as we want.
2. create feed data with desired template(because this success function returns JSON)
3. Slice the feed data and assign to Divs

Find the [demo code here](http://codepen.io/ajithsri/pen/zGNxXG)

```js
    var imgs = [];
    var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'srilanka',
        clientId: '467ede5a6b9b48ae8e03f4e2582aeeb3',
        limit: 20,
        template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}"/></a>',
        success: function (data) {
            // read the feed data and create owr own data struture.
            var images = data.data;
            var result;
            for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                var image = images[i];
                result = this._makeTemplate(this.options.template, {
                    model: image,
                    id: image.id,
                    link: image.link,
                    image: image.images[this.options.resolution].url
                });
                imgs.push(result);
            }
            //split the feed into divs
            $("#instafeed2").html(imgs.slice(0, 5));
            $("#instafeed3").html(imgs.slice(5, 10));
            $("#instafeed4").html(imgs.slice(10, 15));
            $("#instafeed5").html(imgs.slice(15, 20));
        }
    });
    feed.run();
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Example of Instafeed filter data into different divs - Ajith</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://sriajith.info/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/instafeed.min_.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <p>Div1</p>
        <ul id="instafeed2" class="instafeed slides"></ul>
        <p>Div2</p>
        <ul id="instafeed3" class="instafeed slides"></ul>
        <p>Div3</p>
        <ul id="instafeed4" class="instafeed slides"></ul>
        <p>Div4</p>
        <ul id="instafeed5" class="instafeed slides"></ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Superr.. Works like charm. Learnt something new.. Thankuu :)

Comment: Welcome, happy to hear thatuu ;)

Comment: @SrikukanAjith - I can't seem to get it to work and your demo link is not functioning now. I did swap out the client ID...thx

Comment: @arkjoseph - the instafeed library link was broken , now i fixed it and you can check the demo [link](http://codepen.io/ajithsri/pen/zGNxXG) now.

Comment: @SrikukanAjith  Thank you!

Comment: @SrikukanAjith - I seem to be receiving a console error because instafeed is looking for a instafeed unique container.   Do you know how to resolve this?

Comment: @arkjoseph - it's difficult to give the solution without looking the code. If you can share the code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) then it's easy to find the solution :)

Comment: @SrikukanAjith, the console error is actually on your codepen link you provided.